# Javascript mapping nested elements

Tags: javascript

Is there an ES6 way to easily filter out unwanted columns?  Assume we have the following data:

```
const foo = [
  { 
    a:'blah', 
    b:'blah', 
    c:'blah', 
    d:[
      { a:'blah', b:'blah', c:'blah', e:'blah', f:'blah'},
      { a:'blah', b:'blah', c:'blah', e:'blah', f:'blah'},
      { a:'blah', b:'blah', c:'blah', e:'blah', f:'blah'},
      //... N number of objects     
    ],
  },
  { 
    a:'blah', 
    b:'blah', 
    c:'blah', 
    d:[
      { a:'blah', b:'blah', c:'blah', e:'blah', f:'blah'},
      { a:'blah', b:'blah', c:'blah', e:'blah', f:'blah'},
      { a:'blah', b:'blah', c:'blah', e:'blah', f:'blah'},
      //... N number of objects     
    ],
  },
  //... N number of objects     
];
```

I would like to filter out the e and f values so I only have the following:

```
[
  { 
    a:'blah', 
    b:'blah', 
    c:'blah', 
    d:[
      { a:'blah', b:'blah', c:'blah' },
      { a:'blah', b:'blah', c:'blah' },
      { a:'blah', b:'blah', c:'blah' },
      //... N number of objects     
    ],
  },
  { 
    a:'blah', 
    b:'blah', 
    c:'blah', 
    d:[
      { a:'blah', b:'blah', c:'blah' },
      { a:'blah', b:'blah', c:'blah' },
      { a:'blah', b:'blah', c:'blah' },
      //... N number of objects     
    ],
  },
  //... N number of objects     
]
```

I figured it might be something similar to this, though I'm not sure how to handle the d value:

```
.map(x=>{ return {a: x.a, b: x.b, c: x.c, d:x.d}})
```

EDIT: Is there a way to do it without referencing the unwanted values (e or f)? In other words, only by referencing the values you want to keep (a,b,c,d)

Comment: your data is not valid, because arrays can not have properties in literal notation.

Comment: I guess you mean this `d:[
      {a:'blah', b:'blah', c:'blah', e:'blah', f:'blah' }
    ]` instead of this `d:[
      a:'blah', b:'blah', c:'blah', e:'blah', f:'blah'
    ]`

Comment: Fixed the typo. Thanks!

Comment: Can you do this foo.map(x=>{ return {a: x.a, b: x.b, c: x.c, d:x.d.map(xxxxxx) }})

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
const foo=[{a:'blah',b:'blah',c:'blah',d:[{a:'blah',b:'blah',c:'blah',e:'blah',f:'blah'},{a:'blah',b:'blah',c:'blah',e:'blah',f:'blah'},{a:'blah',b:'blah',c:'blah',e:'blah',f:'blah'},],},{a:'blah',b:'blah',c:'blah',d:[{a:'blah',b:'blah',c:'blah',e:'blah',f:'blah'},{a:'blah',b:'blah',c:'blah',e:'blah',f:'blah'},{a:'blah',b:'blah',c:'blah',e:'blah',f:'blah'},],},]

const res = foo.map(({d, ...rest})=>{
  return {...rest, d: d.map(({e,f,...rest})=>({...rest}))}
});

console.log(res);
```

Solution by referencing only wanted variables:

```js
const foo=[{a:'blah',b:'blah',c:'blah',d:[{a:'blah',b:'blah',c:'blah',e:'blah',f:'blah'},{a:'blah',b:'blah',c:'blah',e:'blah',f:'blah'},{a:'blah',b:'blah',c:'blah',e:'blah',f:'blah'},],},{a:'blah',b:'blah',c:'blah',d:[{a:'blah',b:'blah',c:'blah',e:'blah',f:'blah'},{a:'blah',b:'blah',c:'blah',e:'blah',f:'blah'},{a:'blah',b:'blah',c:'blah',e:'blah',f:'blah'},],},]

const res = foo.map(({d, ...rest})=>{
  return {...rest, d: d.map(({a,b,c})=>({a,b,c}))}
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Great, thanks! By any chance is there a way to do it without referencing the unwanted values (e or f)? In other words, only by referencing the values you want to keep (a,b,c,d)

Answer (score 1):

You could destruture unwanted properties and take the rest parameters for properties. for nested array, you need to iterate as well.

```js
const
    filter = ({ e, f, ...rest }) => {
        Object
            .entries(rest)
            .filter(([, v]) => Array.isArray(v))
            .forEach(([k, v]) => Object.assign(rest, { [k]: v.map(filter) }));
        return rest;
    },
    foo = [{ a: 'blah', b: 'blah', c: 'blah', d: [{ a: 'blah', b: 'blah', c: 'blah', e: 'blah', f: 'blah' }, { a: 'blah', b: 'blah', c: 'blah', e: 'blah', f: 'blah' }, { a: 'blah', b: 'blah', c: 'blah', e: 'blah', f: 'blah' }] }, { a: 'blah', b: 'blah', c: 'blah', d: [{ a: 'blah', b: 'blah', c: 'blah', e: 'blah', f: 'blah' }, { a: 'blah', b: 'blah', c: 'blah', e: 'blah', f: 'blah' }, { a: 'blah', b: 'blah', c: 'blah', e: 'blah', f: 'blah' }] }];

console.log(foo.map(filter));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also a solution but not the best one so far:

```
var result = foo.map( e => {
      delete e.d[0].e;
      delete e.d[0].f;
      return e;
});

console.log(result);
```

This work around could be done in a dynamic way

Edit: I made this workaround a little more dynamic:

```
var unwantedIndex = [
  'e', 'f'
];

var r = foo.map( e => {
    for (let data of e.d) {
        for (let indx of unwantedIndex) {
            if (data[indx]) {
                delete data[indx];
            }
        }
    }

   return e;
});

console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

Traverse the array using map and slice the unwanted objects. And the array you created is wrong, it never has key-value pairs. Fixed that too.

```js
const foo = [
  { 
    a:'blah', 
    b:'blah', 
    c:'blah', 
    d:[
      { a:'blah', b:'blah', c:'blah', e:'blah', f:'blah'},
      { a:'blah', b:'blah', c:'blah', e:'blah', f:'blah'},
      { a:'blah', b:'blah', c:'blah', e:'blah', f:'blah'},
      //... N number of objects     
    ],
  },
  { 
    a:'blah', 
    b:'blah', 
    c:'blah', 
    d:[
      { a:'blah', b:'blah', c:'blah', e:'blah', f:'blah'},
      { a:'blah', b:'blah', c:'blah', e:'blah', f:'blah'},
      { a:'blah', b:'blah', c:'blah', e:'blah', f:'blah'},
      //... N number of objects     
    ],
  },
  //... N number of objects     
];
console.log(foo.map((e)=>{

e.d.forEach((x)=>{delete x.e; delete x.f})
return e;
}))
```

Comment: Sorry, fixed my typo. Our structures are different so please recheck the original post